# SQL Proc parameter to insert WHERE clause?

Tags: sql

Consider the below table:

```
myID    theirID    data
----    -------    ----
1       1          100
2       3          110
3       89         200
4       null       300
5       56         210
```

This is very simplified for example purposes but I have a proc that is like this to be the data source for a report:

```
SELECT myId, data
FROM myTable
```

Before that proc runs, however, I would like to run the same proc to check for null data like this:

```
SELECT myId, data
FROM myTable
WHERE theirId IS NULL
```

Now, unlike my examples, my actual proc is complicated and I don't want to duplicate it. Instead, I want to have a parameter that shows the offending data. So my question is this - how can I build something like this:

```
create proc myProc (checkForBadData bit)
begin
    SELECT myId, data
    FROM myTable
    "but if checkForBadData = 1 then include 'WHERE theirId IS NULL'"
end
```

Can I insert only one little bit of dynamic SQL on the end, or do I have to pollute the whole thing?

Thanks!

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to your where clause, and you shouldn't need to have any dynamic sql.

```
create proc myProc (checkForBadData bit)
begin
    SELECT myId, data
    FROM myTable
    WHERE checkForBadData = 0 or theirId IS NULL
end
```

Comment: Perfect. I have used that method many times before - brainfart.